# Time to promote an APK from beta to production

Tags: android, google-play

I understand that publishing an APK directly to production (or alpha/beta) takes some time (1-6 hours), but what about promoting from beta (or alpha) to production?

Is it a shorter time period or does it take a similar amount of time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just went through this process and it took approximately one hour to promote from beta to production. It does not appear instant, so I can only presume it uses the same process of directly uploading to production.